# Swagger 3: Issues with Large JSON Responses and Unwanted "job-id" Endpoints

Tags: java, swagger

I recently migrated a Jakarta EE project to Swagger 3 and added the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-jakarta</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.15</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations-jakarta</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.15</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm facing two issues:

Large JSON Responses: When the JSON response from an endpoint is too large, Swagger UI shows the error "Could not render responses_Responses, see the console." This issue was not present in previous versions. Has anyone encountered this and knows a fix?

Unwanted "job-id" Endpoints: Alongside the documentation for my actual endpoints, Swagger is also generating documentation for some mysterious "job-id" endpoints (GET, POST, DELETE). I have no idea where these are coming from. Has anyone else experienced this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!